# Can't turn on numlock in Gnome shell textbox but everywhere else is fine

Tags: gnome, keyboard, numlock, numpad

Recently, I opened Synaptic and type my password (which include numbers) and notice that numlock isn't turned on no matter how many times I hit <kbd>numlock</kbd> button.

Then I return, open other programs (chrome, gedit, terminal, gksu ...), numlock works fine.

I open some gnome-shell textbox (<kbd>Alt + F2</kbd> to open run box, <kbd>Super</kbd> to open search box, ...), numlock has no effect whatsoever: The numlock LED is still turned on/off when I hit <kbd>numlock</kbd>, but gnome-shell doesn't see it; if I press <kbd>4</kbd> or <kbd>5</kbd>, the text-caret moves left/right.

I have no idea what cause it, at all. I did update softwares and drivers everyday but I use stable versions. I installed `numlockx` but that doesn't fix my problem. I also update linux-image (from `linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic` to `linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic`).

I can still use <kbd>Shift + NumKey</kbd> to type numbers, but this is just annoying.

My gnome-shell version: `3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1`